Evaluating expressions involving Dirac spinors
Consider the Dirac equation $(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\psi=0$.
This equation describes the free Dirac field. Consider the plane wave solutions $\psi(x)=u(\vec{p})e^{-ip\cdot x}$ and $\psi(x)=v(\vec{p})e^{ip\cdot x}$ for $E > 0$ and $E < 0$, respectively, where $E = p^0$. Here $u$ and $v$ are the Dirac spinors for particles and antiparticles. These are four component column matrices. Suppose we explicitly assign a spin index $s$ to $u$ and $v$, which can take two values, and represent spin up and spin down particles. In the Pauli-Dirac reperesenttion of the gamma matrices, I explicitly found the expressions for $u(\vec{p})$ and $v(\vec{p})$. Now, I want to calculate the following expressions:
$$
\sum_{s}{v^s(\vec{p})\bar{v} ^s(\vec{p})},\\
\sum_{s}{v^s(\vec{p})\bar{v} ^s(\vec{p})},
$$
where $\bar{\psi}=\psi^{\dagger}\gamma^0$ is the Dirac adjoint of the spinor $\psi$.
My attemp at solution:
In the Dirac representation, the gamma matrices are given by ($I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ unit matrix)
$$
\gamma^0=\sigma^3\otimes I_2, \gamma^j=i\sigma^{2}\otimes\sigma^j.
$$
Putting the plane wave ansatz for $E>0$ and $E<0$ in the Dirac equation, I got the equations for $u(\vec{p})$ and $v(\vec{p})$:
$$
(p\!\!\!/-m)u(\vec{p})=0\\
(p\!\!\!/+m)v(\vec{p})=0
$$
In the block matrix form, we have, for $E>0$,
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}(E-m)I_2&-\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}\\\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}&-(E+m)I_2\\\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}u_1\\u_2\\\end{matrix}\right)=0
$$
This contains two matrix equations in the two component column matrices $u_1$ and $u_2$, of which the second equation is relevant as $E>0$ in this case, and we have
$$
u_2=\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m}u_1,
$$
which gives
$$
u(\vec{p})=N\left(\begin{matrix}I_2\\\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m}\end{matrix}\right)u_1
$$
where $u_1$ can be taken as either $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\\end{matrix}\right)$ or $\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\\end{matrix}\right)$, (depending on the spin index $s$ representing it as a spin up or spin down particle) and $N$ is a normalization constant, given by
$$
\rho=u^{\dagger}u=\bar{u}\gamma^0u=|N|^2u_1^{\dagger}\left(\begin{matrix}I_2&\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m}\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}I_2\\\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m}\\\end{matrix}\right)u_1=|N|^2\frac{2E}{E+m}.
$$
Hence, choosing $\rho=2E$ gives $|N|=\sqrt{E+m}$.
Similarly, for $E<0$, we have
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}(E+m)I_2&-\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}\\\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}&-(E-m)I_2\\\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}v_1\\v_2\\\end{matrix}\right)=0
$$
and by a similar reasoning, we have for $E<0$,
$$
v_2=\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E-m}v_1,
$$
which gives
$$
v(\vec{p})=N'\left(\begin{matrix}I_2\\\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E-m}\end{matrix}\right)v_1\\
\rho'=-2E,\\|N'|=\sqrt{m-E}
$$
Now comes the main evaluation. While I am getting the correct expression for $E>0$ case,
$$
\sum_{s}{u^s(\vec{p})\bar{u} ^s(\vec{p})}=p\!\!\!/+m,
$$
I am wondering that the expression I got for
$$
\sum_{s}{v^s(\vec{p})\bar{v} ^s(\vec{p})}=-p\!\!\!/+m
$$
is correct or not. Maybe the sign is reversed. Someone please be kind enough to help me.
